# Method correspoding with define "style" in XML

Tags: android

I customize a button in Android. I have a class like this

```
class MyButton extends Button{
}
```

then in the layout file i have the define like this:

```
<MyButton android:id="@+id/abc"
    style = "@style/ButtonStyle">
</MyButton>
```

My question is: How can i call method to embedded the "style" into the code of "MyButton"? So i can use in the layout file just this one but it have the effect like have the "style":

```
<MyButton android:id="@+id/abc"
    >
</MyButton>
```

Comment: in your constructor, when calling super, one parameter is the style (the last one)

Comment: It doesn't work, i tried
   public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
  super(context, attrs, R.style.MyButtonStyle);
 }


With R.style.MyButtonStyle is the define of style button in "styles.xml"

Comment: are you creating it from code or from xml?

Comment: I create it from the code.